# Switching regulator vs converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, switching-regulator, step-down

Is there any difference between switching regulators and converters? I have read about step-down voltage regulator and buck converters and they seem to be the same. So, can I use the term converter instead of switching regulator or is not it the same?
For example, in LM2596 datasheet, are use both terms to describe the circuit.

Comment: The difference is between "Switching" and  "Linear".

Comment: Something that calls itself a regulator is going to regulate the voltage; a converter may not necessarily (but almost all of them do).

Comment: A converter could mean anything that er.. converts.

Comment: But for a step-down switching regulator, can I also use the term of ”Buck converter”? Or is there a difference between these 2 circuits?

Comment: One does not imply the other @Anna - A step-down switching regulator doesn't always imply a buck type conversion.

Comment: @Andyaka If I use a LM2596 with 12V input voltage and 6V output voltage, I think it's irrelevant if I use switching regulator and Buck converter to ”name” the circuit. Am I right?

Comment: @Anna \$ apple \Rightarrow fruit \$, but \$ fruit \nRightarrow apple \$. You can safely say "switching regulator."

Comment: A simple [Joule Thief](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) self-oscillating boost converter does not regulate by virtue of the fact that there is no feedback based upon the output voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-down Voltage Regulator:** A device that converts a voltage to a lower voltage, and regulates the output to a constant voltage. It may use linear or switching topology.

**Buck Converter:** A device that steps voltage down by switching the input on and off rapidly and feeding it into an inductor to 'buck' the voltage.

All buck converters are step-down converters, and most are regulated.

Not all step-down converters are buck converters. They can instead use a transformer, capacitors (eg. [LTC1503](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc1503.html#product-overview)), or a linear series pass element.  Linear regulators can only reduce the voltage, but switching regulators may also be able to increase it (in which case they are called 'boost' or 'buck/boost' regulators). Transformer based converters often have a [galvanically isolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation) output which can be used alone or connected to another voltage source to increase the voltage. The term 'DC/DC converter' encompasses all devices that convert one DC voltage to another DC voltage - whether switching or linear, regulated or unregulated, isolated or not.